# Flutter pinput package in web pwa

Tags: flutter, dart

Hi is there any way to use the auto fill feature of Pinput package in web PWA ? like android and iOS.

i have checked some stactoverflow issue and also the issues in GitHub but didn't find any question or answer on if its working or not